# How to remove newline in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have got the content of a div as a string (assume the string name is `str` ) using `html()` method. Div content is basically a table like this.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>MMMK</td></tr>
<table>
```

So how can i remove newline of the string (`str`) if the new line found inside `<td>string \n Other string line</td>` that newline should not remove. Why i'm doing this ? because i need to get the content of the div and set to a `text area`. After set the text to `textarea` form submitted and place the `textarea` content to a page. Before place the `textarea` content to the page i use `nl2br()` method in `PHP`. So how can i do this?

Comment: Use `trim()` (and Google). http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: @JayBlanchard i used `trim()` . But its not working.

Comment: How is not working @Harshana? Please provide the code and the markup that you used along with a detailed explanation of what happened/did not happen that you expected/didn't expect. Maybe even setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `$.trim` definitely works here @Harshana http://jsbin.com/jixobuva/1/edit

Comment: @JayBlanchard if i use trim() the remove the all the newlines. But i not need to remove all the newlines. If newline in <td></td> shouldn't remove ..

Comment: @Harshana did you read the docs on `trim()`? "The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. **If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.**" Until we see some code and markup we will only be speculating on how your issue should be handled.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i read it. And i know it. check use of the `trim()` and placing value in side text area and after use the nl2br() that automatically creates <br > tag in side the new page .. check and reply .

Comment: most of the people only see the all of the question as a simple question. Check before reply. :'(

Comment: Most people see their questions as complex but fail to provide enough information to get their problem solved properly. Check before asking - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/********************************************************************************/
// Replaces newlines on everything except what is in the given tags

function nl2br_excluding($string, $open, $close) {

    $substring = array();

    // Strip the backslashes so we have a clean representation of the tags.
    $open_tag = stripslashes($open);
    $close_tag = stripslashes($close);

    $count = preg_match_all("#$open(.*?)$close#si", $string, $matches);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        // Save the substring between the tags in a numbered array.
        $substring[$i] = $matches[1][$i];

        // Replace the substring within the tags with a number so we can replace it later.
        $match = $open_tag.$substring[$i].$close_tag;
        $replace = $open_tag.$i.$close_tag;

        $string = str_replace($match, $replace, $string);
    }

    $string = nl2br($string);

    // After replacing the newlines go back through our substring array and put them back
    // based on their key values.

    foreach($substring as $i => $value) {
        $match = $open_tag.$i.$close_tag;
        $replace = $open_tag.$value.$close_tag;
        $string = str_replace($match, $replace, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Then call

```
nl2br_excluding($string,"<td>","</td>");
```

Source: http://hawkee.com/snippet/9705/

Comment: thats ok. But i not need to remove all the newlines. If newline in <td></td> shouldn't remove :(

Comment: Extend your preg to include .*<td> to match whats before the open tage and </td>.* for whats after it then.

Comment: can u please tell me with explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got some idea with your answer. Thanks for your kind attention of my question. Your are the one who commented as ethical person. Thanks. your answer is correct for my question. Thanks again ..